# Regular expression for all characters except 0 and 1 in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I try to find number of occurrence of 011 in binary strings that are delimited by any other (e.g. `11100011/100010-01110a0011100b`) characters. So I need to say allcharacters-[0,1] somewhere in my code to use split function. How could I say it in regular expression...

Comment: I mere match the 011 in the string but considering all the string. I could not separate binary strings from delimiters. So If I get to know how to say in regex allchars except 0 and 1 I will use split function and take each binary string to an element of a array.

Answer (score 7):

You can invert a character set by prefixing it with `^`:

```
[^01]
```

In this case, however, you don't need to use `split` at all:

```
my @binary_strings = $input =~ m{[01]+}g;
```

Comment: m{[0-1]+}g what is the 'g' functioning here?

Comment: Causes the regular expression to return all matches, rather than just the first one.

Comment: I’m not sure I’d use a hyphen between the `0` and the `1` there. It’s not like there’s actually anything between the two of them.

Comment: @tchrist: Whoops - not sure why I added that. Fixed.